# All Wheel Drive 2010 Toyota Venza vibration/shaking

Tags: differential, rear-differential

My 2010 AWD Toyota Venza vibrates when I am driving at 35-55 km/h. The vibration seems to go away at speeds below 35 km/h or higher than 55 km/h.
During vibration the steering wheel does not shake at all and the tires should be fine too since they have recently been replaced with new all season ones. There however seems to be a leak at the rear differential (where Electro Magnetic coupler is located). I was wondering if the vibration is caused by the differential? And if so do i need to replace the EM coupler or the whole rear differential? Also is it something I could do myself? (I have never done it before)

Comment: I ended up replacing the rear differential seals and the vibration was resolved a few days after the seal replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a badly balanced tire to me, sometimes the tire shop doesn't get it right or a weight falls off. I'd take it back to the shop you got the tires from and get them re-balanced.

Answer (score 0):

A vibration having a narrow resonance is easy.

Tyres resonate at 70-100km/h and the vibration is few times per second.

What you have is probably a propeller shaft imbalance or worn out bearing at rear diff.

It may also be a different tyre diameter front/rear causing the EM coupler to engage. ( Are tyres all the same? Are they rotated every 5000 or so km? ).

A minor leak is OK on any diff. A major leak means overheat or a bearing going bad.

As for doing it yourself: on older car I would recommend temporarily removing the propeler shaft to see if the vibration disappears. Not that anything on your car will mechanicaly break, but running with the shaft removed may drive the EM computer crazy.